# Clone and insertAfter only once a time with jQuery

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<p class="field-other">other</p>
<p class="field-new">new</p>
<p><a class="add-new" href="#">add new</a></p>
```

jQuery

```
$('.field-new').hide();

$('.add-new').click( function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.field-new').clone().insertAfter('.field-new').show();
    return false;
});
```

Can anyone help please? So one click on ".add-new" to add only one new field ".field-new". Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use `.first()` or `.prev()` method:

```
$(this.parentNode).siblings('.field-new')
                  .first()
                  .clone()
                  .insertAfter('.field-new')
                  .show();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvHXM/1/)

or:

```
$(this.parentNode).prev('.field-new')
                  .clone()
                  .insertBefore(this.parentNode);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvHXM/)